# python selenium cant iterate through elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, selenium

Trying to iterate though a list of elements by the index of a class. Each attempt the index doesnt increase. Adding quotes around %s produces an invalid syntax error.

```
 lengeItem = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="baobab"]'))
 i=1
 for i in range(lengeItem):
        Domaino = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='baobab']['%s']/p/a" % i).text
        print (Domaino)


        print (Domaino)
```

Comment: Just a note, setting `i` equal to 1 right before the iteration does nothing. And that particular iteration, the way you have it set will begin at zero.

Comment: what output of `['%s+']` do you expect?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i is an integer, you need to use %d, not %s 
and don't wrap it in quotes, this should work: [%d]

```
 els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="baobab"]')
 for i, el in enumerate(els):
        print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='baobab'][%d]/p/a" % (i + 1)).text
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='baobab'][%s]/p/a" % i).text`

If i is 1, then `%s` is `'1'`. Since you are trying index using string `td[@class='baobab']['1']` which throws error.  It should be `td[@class='baobab'][1]`